# Title Loop within For Loop

Tags: for-loop, matplotlib

I need to loop through the titles in the list and I cannot seem to do so without printing the entire list every time or looping through the graphs multiple times. Thanks in advance!

```
title = ["West", "Plains", "Midwest", "Southeast", "Northeast"]
State_list = [West_df,Plains_df,Midwest_df,Southeast_df,Northeast_df]

title = ["West", "Plains", "Midwest", "Southeast", "Northeast"]
State_list = [West_df,Plains_df,Midwest_df,Southeast_df,Northeast_df]

for index in range(len(State_list)):
    #Plot bar chart with county and population
    df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(State_list[index],values="Population",index="County",columns="State")
    # Plot a bar chart using the DF
    ax = df_pivot.plot(kind="bar")
    fig = ax.get_figure()
    mplcursors.cursor(fig)
    # Change the plot dimensions (width, height)
    fig.set_size_inches(15, 6)
    # Change the axes labels
    ax.set_xlabel("County")
    ax.set_ylabel("Population")
    plt.title(f"Region: {title} | Population Recorded in each County")
    #Plot scatter plot with deaths per capita, 
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
    plt.xlabel("Cases of Covid")
    plt.ylabel("Deaths per Capita")
    (slope, intercept, rvalue, pvalue, stderr) = linregress(State_list[index]["Cases"], State_list[index]["Deaths per Capita"])
    regress_values = State_list[index]["Cases"] * slope + intercept
    line_eq = "y = " + str(round(slope,8)) + "x + " + str(round(intercept,5))
    Scatter2 = plt.scatter(State_list[index]["Cases"], State_list[index]["Deaths per Capita"],s=State_list[index]["Heart Disease"]*.3,
            c=State_list[index].State.astype('category').cat.codes)
    plt.plot(State_list[index]["Cases"],regress_values,color = "purple")
    plt.annotate(line_eq,(10000,.007),fontsize=15,color = "purple")
    plt.annotate(f"The r-squared is: {rvalue**2}",(10000,.0067),fontsize=10,color = "purple")
    plt.title(f"Region: {title} | Deaths per Capita recorded by County in regards to Heart Disease")
    #Hover Event
    mplcursors.cursor(Scatter2, hover=True)
    plt.legend(loc = "upper right",ncol= 2, handles=Scatter2.legend_elements()[0], 
           labels=State_list[index],
           title="State")
```

Comment: Did you try title[index]?

Comment: Yes, I was able to get it running by adding